# Metric space isometries and integration by substitution

Tags: integration, measure-theory, metric-spaces, isometry, change-of-variable

Let $X$ be a locally compact metric space.

Assume that a commutative operation "$+$" is defined on $X$ with $(X,+)$ forming a group.

Assume further that for any $y\in X$, $x\mapsto x+y$ is a bijective isometry. (We say $h:X\rightarrow X$ is an isometry iff for all $x_1,x_2 \in X$, $d(x_1,x_2)=d(f(x_1),f(x_2))$.)

Let $\int_X \cdot \,dx$ denote the integral formed from the Haar measure on the locally compact topological group $(X,+)$.

What is the weakest possible additional assumption for it to be true that for all bijective isometries $f:X\rightarrow X$:
$$\int_X {g(x)\,dx}=\int_X {g(f(x))\,dx}$$
for all functions $g:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for which the integrals are defined.

---

Notes:

1. If $X=\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is a shift and/or reflection, and the claimed result holds by a trivial substitution.
2. If $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual metric, then $f$ is a translation followed by a unitary transformation, so the result again goes through. It is not clear that it holds with non-standard metrics though.
3. The result also holds for circles and spheres with the standard metric.
4. The claimed result will not hold in general if $f$ is not an isometry. For example, take $X=[0, 1]$, $g(x)=x$ and $f(x)=x^2$.

I would guess that the missing condition ensures that the metric in some sense agrees with the measure. For example, consider the Manhattan or max metrics on Euclidean space. They generate the same topology and thus (?) the same Haar measure, but it seems unlikely the integral condition holds for these metrics.

---

New note: This question (just discovered) is clearly very closely related: [Existence of isometry-invariant measures](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2817855/existence-of-isometry-invariant-measures?rq=1)

The only missing step is from the invariance of the measure to the invariance of the integral, but I guess this is trivial.

Comment: Your question is phrased as a stand-alone question and, as such, is likely to be closed for lack of context.  You could provide some indication of what you've tried already, why this interests you, and anything else that would make this a useful resource for other users.

Comment: I'm an academic, but not in maths. I haven't tried much as I assumed this would be a standard result for which someone could point me to an answer! Don't mathematicians love maths for maths sake? This question arises when thinking about defining (in some sense) "stationary" stochastic processes over spaces other than just the real line. This is a long way from the topic of the question, and there are several intermediate steps, so I'm not sure my context would be very useful!

Comment: @postmortes Further to the above, I have added a few brief notes to the question. They are all immediately obvious points, so I'm not sure if this is really the context you were looking for.

Comment: The integral isn't an intrinsically defined thing but requires to consider some fixed measure. If the [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration) you have fixed isn't invariant under the isometry $f$, the formula will be false, take for example the [Dirac measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure) of one point.

Comment: @Didier Helpful! So when does a measure exist that is invariant under all isometries? I guess I was implicitly assuming such a measure, like the usual Lebesgue one.

Comment: The fact that the isometry group is locally compact is a strong assumption on the metric!

Comment: @Didier I've now read a bit more. So suppose that there is an addition operation on the space which is an isometry (for any fixed second argument), and that the measure is the corresponding Haar measure. Is that enough?

Comment: @Didier I was just editing my previous comment when you replied. I see now.

Comment: @Didier I have now specified a Haar measure in the question. I am still not sure that is enough for my claim to hold though. What goes wrong with the Manhattan metric?

Comment: Hausdorff measure?!

Comment: I wasn't thinking of Hausdorff measures, no.

Comment: For your example $4$ ($X=[0,1]$) what is the law $+$ that you consider?

Comment: Good question! That example is left from an earlier draft of this question.

Comment: One possibility is addition "mod 1". The fractional part after addition.